# users should not see other journals excpts their journal which created by them only

Tags: erp

[I need to give access that they should onyl able to see their journal in dynamics d365 F&O](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqcWp.png)

Dynamics 365 For finanace and operation - general journal

[I need to give access that they should onyl able to see their journal in dynamics d365 F&O](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqcWp.png)

Dynamics 365 For finanace and operation - general journal
[I need to give access that they should onyl able to see their journal in dynamics d365 F&O](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqcWp.png)

Dynamics 365 For finanace and operation - general journal